# Python pccolor plot with two with two x axis description

Tags: python, matplotlib, 2d, axes

The dataset I'm working with are wind velocity observations from a satelite. I have got 2d array of the dimension (192,24) where 24 is the number of vertical range bins: wind_velocity(192,24), latitude(192,24), longitude(192,24), altitude(192,24),...
To get an overview I would like to plot the data. I think the right tool for plotting 2d arrays with python is pccolor. The aim is to get a figure with latitude and longitude on the x-axis, the height on the y-axis and colored the wind data(wind_velocity variable name is hlos here)

```
wind_min, wind_max = hlos.min(), hlos.max()
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
c1 = ax1.pcolor(lats, z, hlos, cmap='RdBu' , vmin = wind_min, vmax = wind_max)
ax1.set_title('Rayleigh HLOS')
ax1.axis([lats.min(), lats.max(), z.min(), z.max()])
fig.colorbar(c1, ax=ax1)
```

How can I add the longitude values so that it looks like the subplot down left on this example: https://www.ecmwf.int/sites/default/files/Aeolus-Blog-image1-1000pix.jpg ?

Comment: What issues are you having? What does your current plot look like?

Comment: You can manually format the xticks, and include a carriage return in each tick value.  See the dates in the bottom right plot made here:  https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/multiline.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-multiline-py